# Meteor pagination

Tags: meteor, pagination

i am struggling with adding in pagination for my forums. Could you help me out? Basically, I was expecting on my forums page, to only see 10 posts. but it is returning all of them. The "Load More" button also does nothing (it seems like).

I am using this package: [Paginated Subscription](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/paginated-subscription)

Here is the code I am using:

```
    if (Meteor.isClient) {

Deps.autorun(function() {
var handle = Meteor.subscribeWithPagination('posts',10);

});

Template.postsList.helpers({
    'posts': function(){
        return Posts.find({});
    }
});

Template.postsList.events({
    'click .btn': function(){
        handle.loadNextPage();
    }
})

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
Meteor.startup(function () {
Meteor.publish("posts", function(limit){
return Posts.find({}, {limit: limit});
});

});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `var handle = Meteor.subscribeWithPagination('posts',10);` Needs to be in the `Deps` block unless you are passing some reactive parameter to the`handle`.

See this [Issue](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-paginated-subscription/issues/6) on Github.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Kurounin](https://github.com/Kurounin/PaginationExample) subscribe based pagination.It works for me.In atmospherejs, there is an another react pagination you can check it in Kurounin repository

Answer (score 0):

I have already answered this kind of pagination to one of question. Please refer the exact code that can help you.

[Meteor Pagination Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458125/meteor-pagination-issue/45460351#45460351)

Answer (score 0):

In your publication you must use **sort** (as documentation says)

> // Using sort here is necessary to continue to use the Oplog Observe
>   Driver!
>
> // https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver

```
Meteor.publish("posts", function(limit){
  return Posts.find({}, {
    limit: limit,
    sort: {
      createdAt: -1
    }
  });
});
```