# Meteor Pagination Issue

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, pagination

I am having issues with pagination I've implemented. Pagination works based on server-sided publish skip & limit filter.

Issue #1.
If I perform a specific user search the very first page will be blank.
[image]

At that state skip is set to 0, limit is always 20.

If I perform a find().fetch() I get 20 elements, but they are all for a different user.
[image]

Issue #2  Me going to next page (skip+10) gives me a **few more** elements
[image]

Doing it again gives **even more** results
[image]

and finally being out of data, and going to next page **just removes 10 results, leaving 10 shown**
[image]

This is a very odd behavior.
Server-sided publish

```
Meteor.publish('overtime', function(opt){
if (!Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, 'admin')) {
return Overtime.find({userId: this.userId}, opt);
} else {
return Overtime.find({}, opt);
}
});
```

Client-sided subscription

```
var defaultSkipStep = 10;
var defaultLimit = 20;
Template.triphtml.onCreated(function(){
 var instance = this;
 Session.set('limit',defaultLimit);
 instance.autorun(function(){


instance.subscribe('overtime', {skip:(Session.get('overSkip')||0), limit:(Session.get('limit')||defaultLimit), sort: {createdAt: -1}});
instance.subscribe('trips', {skip:(Session.get('tripSkip')||0), limit:(Session.get('limit')||defaultLimit), sort: {createdAt: -1}});
});
```

Next page click event

```
"click .nxtpage_over": function(event, template){
Session.set('overSkip', (Session.get('overSkip') || 0) + defaultSkipStep);
Session.set('limit', 20);
},
```

Submit event
https://pastebin.com/btYCSQBD

Query that user sees 
main.js (client)

https://pastebin.com/tWakPDT1

main.html
https://pastebin.com/4uMVFsNG

Any idea how to make it so that when I perform search for a specific user I get all 20 results just for that user, and next page gives me NEXT 20 elements, not showing any one the 20 I've just seen.

Comment: your code is really very messy (sorry for that comment). If you allow me I can share my pagination code with you which is very simple with global serach. all works at server-side publish, very efficient and very robust.

Comment: Dont use session for pagination. Use template reactive-vars as I did in below code. If you have trouble understanding my code, let me know, I' will explain in brief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code for pagination. It is very ideal code, easy to understand and implement.

**SERVER PUBLISH:**

```
        Meteor.publish('Students', function (str, toSkip, tillLimit) {
        var regex = new RegExp(str, 'i');
        var data = Students.find( {
                                $or:[
                                    {"_id": {'$regex' : regex}},
                                    {"username": {'$regex' : regex}}
                                ]
                            },
                    {sort: {'time': -1}, skip: toSkip, limit : tillLimit});
      return data;
    });

    Meteor.publish('StudentsTotalCount', function (str) {
        var regex = new RegExp(str, 'i');
        Counts.publish(this, "StudentsTotalCount", Students.find({
                                $or:[
                                    {"_id": {'$regex' : regex}},
                                    {"username": {'$regex' : regex}}
                                ]
                            });
          );
    });
```

`str` is global search text from client side. Now, Since the user will click on `next` and `previous` button frequently. On the client side the Subscription must be reactive. For that you can you below code.

**CLIENT SUBSCRIBE:**

Inside some `App_ShowStudents.js` file, you can create subscription as below;

```
    Template.App_ShowStudents.onCreated(function(){
      this.userId = new ReactiveVar("");
      this.filterCriteria = new ReactiveVar("");
      //PAGINATION
      this.enablePrevious = new ReactiveVar(false);
      this.enableNext = new ReactiveVar(true);
      this.skip = new ReactiveVar(0);
      this.diff = new ReactiveVar(0);
      this.total = new ReactiveVar(0);
      this.limit = new ReactiveVar(10);

      this.autorun(() => {
        Meteor.subscribe('Students', this.filterCriteria.get(), this.skip.get(), this.limit.get());
        Meteor.subscribe('StudentsTotalCount', this.filterCriteria.get(), this.role.get());
      });
    });
```

**HELPERS:**

```
    Template.App_ShowStudents.helpers({
        students(){
            return Students.findOne({}); // this will always be less or equal to 10.
        },
          skip(){
            return Template.instance().skip.get();
          },
          diff(){
            var instance = Template.instance();
            var add = instance.skip.get() + instance.limit.get();
            var total = instance.total.get();
            var diff = (add >= total ? total : add);
            instance.diff.set(diff);
            return instance.diff.get();
          },
          total(){
            Template.instance().total.set(Counts.get('StudentsTotalCount'));
            return Template.instance().total.get();
          }
    });
```

`total` actually must be reactive and should give only count as per your search criteria, so we had a seperate publish on server.

**EVENTS:**

```
    Template.App_ShowStudents.events({
        'click .previous': function (event, template) {
             event.preventDefault();
             if(template.diff.get() > template.limit.get()){
               template.skip.set(template.skip.get() - template.limit.get());
             }
          },
        'click .next': function (event, template) {
         event.preventDefault();
         if(template.diff.get() < template.total.get()){
           template.skip.set(template.skip.get() + template.limit.get());
         }
        },
        'input #searchData': function( event, template ) {
            if ( $( event.target ).val()) { // has some value.
              template.filterCriteria.set( $( event.target ).val() );
            } else {
              template.filterCriteria.set( "" );
            }
            console.log(template.filterCriteria.get());
          },
    });
```

**App_ShowStudents.html**

```
    <template name="App_ShowStudents">
       {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
            <body>
                <input type="text" id="searchData" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Search ID, Username" />
                Showing {{skip}} - {{diff}} of {{total}}
                {{#each students}}
                    ...
                {{/each}}
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#" role="button" class="previous">Previous</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" role="button" class="next">Next</a></li>
                </ul>
            </body>
        {{else}}
            Please wait...
        {{/if}}
    </template>
```

Comment: Okay, I will try and let you know if using following code for my purposes works :D

Comment: Brother, it has to work. you have much better UI to club above code and make it working. also dont forget to install `tmeasday:publish-counts` package. You have to use above code as it is except your collection publications

Comment: I made it working fully based on code above but a bit differently. I used to subscribe to collections with certain limit and skip, and filter on client-side. Now I subscribe to limit, skip and a filter, and everything works flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: If you liked my solution, you could upvote my answer. That will be encouraging.

Comment: I thought that ticking the best answer option is the same as up vote. sorry :D

Comment: by the way, which theme are you using for your application. I would like to know. I liked it.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 3 for Meteor, however I would recommend using Materialize instead