# Meteor js: The page taking too much time to query with mongodb if records are around 100000

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am working on meteor js, there will be huge data in mongodb database. For now it is around 50000 messages in database. I am providing the code that I am currently using. For some reason the application is taking too much time to render or load the data from database. Also one more thing, if I am doing any activity,e.g. just like the messages the app fetches the messages again from database.

```
Template.messages.helper({
    linkMessages() {
        var ids = _.pluck(Meteor.user().subscription, '_id');
        var messages = Messages.find({ $or: [{ feedId: { $exists: false }, link: { $exists: true } }, { feedId: { $in: ids }, link: { $exists: true } }] }, { sort: { timestamp: 1 }, limit: Session.get("linkMessageLimit") }).fetch();
        return messages;
    }

})
```

calling publication in oncreate method

```
Template.roomView.onCreated(function() {
    const self = this;
    Deps.autorun(function() {
        Meteor.subscribe('messages', Session.get('currentRoom'), Session.get('textMessageLimit'), {
            onReady() {
                isReady.messages = true;
                if (scroll.needScroll) {
                    scroll.needScroll = false;
                    if (scroll.previousMessage) {
                        Client.scrollToMessageText(scroll.previousMessage);
                    }
                } else {
                    Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
                        Client.scrollChatToBottomMsg();
                    }, 1000)
                }
            }
        });

    });
});`
```

The publication function on  server:

```
Meteor.publish('messages', function(roomId, limit) {
    check(roomId, String);
    check(limit, Match.Integer);

        let query = { $or: [{ link: {$exists: false} }, { feedId: { $exists: false } }] };

        const thresholdMessage = Messages.findOne(query, { skip: limit, sort: { timestamp: 1 } });

        if (thresholdMessage && thresholdMessage.timestamp) {
            query.timestamp = { $gt: thresholdMessage.timestamp };
        }

        return Messages.find(query, { sort: { timestamp: -1 } });

});
```

Comment: [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) cannot use an index. Surely there is something more useful you can query on than that? If not then you need to re-design how you are storing data and make it so that the "value" of a field is what you are querying, rather than the "presence" of a field in the document.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried without $exists, a simple find query, Still its taking time to load.

Comment: why you need to publish all 50K records on UI?

Comment: No i don't want the 50k records on ui, I am fetching just 100 records at a time on ui by specifying the limit, To find that 100 records and render them on view it is taking time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good practice to allow mini-mongodb to get populated with such a huge data. Though Meteor JS is good at this too, still it will take some amount of time taking into consideration the network traffic, bandwidth etc.

Irrespective of whether it is *unlimited scroll* or *simple pagination* I would suggest you to use pagination. I have already got it accepted and it works like charm, [here is the answer and entire code for pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458125/meteor-pagination-issue/45460351#45460351).

My pagination solution is server specific, so it performs good. Collection publish is limited to the `limit` provided from subscription.

> NOTE: There is yet no such proper full fledged solution for table with search and pagination and much more facility which makes it very flexible as per our need. I suggest to create your own.

**MORE INSIGHTS:**

https://www.quora.com/Does-Meteor-work-well-with-large-datasets

https://forums.meteor.com/t/very-big-data-collection-in-mongodb-how-to-fetch-in-meteor-js/6571/7

https://projectricochet.com/blog/top-10-meteor-performance-problems

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now i am fetching only 20 records at a time from the collection. and its working good now. But when i am updating just one record from that 20 records its taking same time to update that record.

Comment: can you please accept the answer above if you felt that it helped you? and also post your subscription, publishing code for pagination. I can definitely help.