# Meteor js custom pagination

Tags: meteor, pagination, meteor-blaze, meteor-collections

I kindly need a support. I have written a pagination following a YouTube tutorial, which works fine with the exception of when going backwards again. It has only 2 buttons, `previous` and `next`, when the next button is clicked it works fine but the previous button only go backwards once. Let's say I have 20 records in the collections paginated to display 5 at a time, the next button could go to the end to the fourth page but the previous button would not go pass one step backwards. Please what am I to do  to have pagination experience? The previous button is suppose to navigate to the last page as long as the user clicks.

**Events for the pagination buttons**:

```js
Template.myviews.events({
  'click .previous': function () {
    if (Session.get('skip') > 5 ) {
      Session.set('skip', Session.get('skip') - 5 );
    }
  },
  'click .next': function () {
    Session.set('skip', Session.get('skip') + 5 );
  }
});
```

**Publication**:

```js
Meteor.publish('userSchools', function (skipCount) {
  check(skipCount, Number);
  user = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: this.userId });
  if(user) {
    if(user.emails[0].verified) {
      return SchoolDb.find({userId: Meteor.userId()}, {limit: 5, skip: skipCount});
    } else {
      throw new Meteor.Error('Not authorized');
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

**Subscription**:

```js
Session.setDefault('skip', 0);
Tracker.autorun(function () {
  Meteor.subscribe('userSchools', Session.get('skip'));
});
```

**Blaze pagination buttons**:

```html
<ul class="pager">
  <li class="previous"><a href="#">Previous</a> </li>
  <li class="next"><a href="#">Next</a> </li>
</ul>
```

**Template helper**:

```js
RenderSchool: function () {
  if(Meteor.userId()) {
    if(Meteor.user().emails[0].verified) {
      return SchoolDb.find({userId: Meteor.userId()}).fetch().reverse();
    } else {
      FlowRouter.go('/');
      Bert.alert('Please verify your account to proceed', 'success', 'growl-top-right');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show template and helper as well?

Comment: THanks, Styx, I have updated the code, added the helper.

Comment: And how many items do you have in your collection exactly?

Comment: I have 6 documents. Though , for my test I set limit: 2, so I should have 3 pages.

Comment: @kehinde: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458125/meteor-pagination-issue/45460351#45460351 I have used Reactive-var instead of Session variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 6 documents total with 2 docs per page, 3 pages in total.

Your `if` condition in `previous` button click handler prevents you from going to the first page:

```js
if (Session.get('skip') > 2 /* testing */ ) {
  ...
}
```

For 2nd page `skip` will equal `2` and on the next click this condition will be `false`, preventing from going back.

When you're on the 3rd page — you can go on 2nd only, creating an impression that button works only once.

It should be like this:

```js
if (Session.get('skip') > 0 ) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: THanks Styx. I immensely appreciate your professional contribution. To your answer I only added this `Session.get('skip') > 0 || Session.get('skip') > 2`. It is now working perfectly.

Comment: @kehinde This addition doesn't make sense. If `skip > 0` then the second part of condition won't even evaluate.

Comment: Yes. Truly. I have reverted to your suggestion.